# How to show a progress bar in a p4v custom tool which performs p4 sync operation?

Tags: perforce, p4v

So I am writing a powershell script which performs a "`p4 sync`" operation after reading the revision number from an external file.
I'd like to show some progress bar for this operation. How to achieve this as the p4 sync starts performing it task directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the command:

```
p4 -I sync -q
```

you'll get a progress spinner in the terminal window.  If you want a GUI progress bar, you will need to implement one yourself (there isn't a way to hook into the progress bar in P4V, so you'd need to launch your own window and render the appropriate graphic).